# Transistor (and Zener) between two power rails

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator

I am repairing a CD Player and I believe the -5V Regulator (bottom) and the transistor between the two output lines to be faulty.

Can I ask though, what is the purpose of the transistor between the +5V and -5V rails? The Zener is 4.7V for info.

The transistor appears to have been fitted in the incorrect orientation but it has been working for years until recently failing?  The transistor is a BC328-16 with CBE pin layout.

Is it possible that transistor failed long ago but the unit still worked correctly until the VR went?  The transistor is swollen on one side but I haven't actually tested it.

[image: circuit diagram]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the circuit does is pull the output of the negative regulator to ground until the positive regulator voltage has come up enough to overcome the zener voltage and turn the transistor off. It would have also grounded the negative if the positive voltage was lost, say from a bad regulator.
Since the 79M05 regulator is internally protected this would have had the effect of shutting off the -5 V.

For whatever reason it appears that they did not want the negative voltage to be active without the positive.

If this circuit failed with the transistor open it may have had no affect on the device operation.

Answer (score 1):

That's a crowbar circuit. If you draw too much current (a short circuit), it throws a crowbar across the 5V rails: it short-circuits the output internally, if the output is short-circuit externally. Normally used in conjunction with a supply fuse, not shown here.

Comment: I looked up Crowbar Circuit and that makes sense but it appears they protect against over-voltage rather than over-current? How would excessive current draw affect the transistor?

Comment: "crowbar circuit" is just a name. It doesn't really tell you what or why they are trying to protect. Normally used with a supply fuse, not shown here: if there is no external supply limit, it's probably not intended for that purpose.

Comment: @MattP It will short the negative supply whenever there is too low of a voltage on the positive supply, one condition that could cause that is excessive current draw on the positive rail. 

Basically anything that reduces the positive supply voltage below the threshold set by the zener will cause the transistor to short the negative supply, several different things could activate it but it's hard to say which specific set of conditions the designers had in mind.